# using file_get_contents twice with a variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i am trying to use this bit of code to first retrieve a URL that is stored in a txt file on my server and save it as a variable, then run file_get_contents a second time using the URL i just retrieved and saved as a variable.

the code works for the first file_get_contents and echoes the URL that is stored, but fails to then use that URL in the second file_get_contents to echo the contents of the URL.

```
<?php
$files = file_get_contents('http://example.com/txtfile.txt');
echo $files;
$file = file_get_contents($files);
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: What result do you get when you echo $files?

Comment: What's in `txtfile.txt`?

Comment: maybe there's some whitespace that gets included, or the url needs to be urlencoded. try file_get_contents(trim($files));

Comment: the $files echo gives me the URL that is stored in the txt file.

Comment: it seems ANDREW M that trim does indeed work! i will have to do some further testing but at first glance it works!

Comment: @Andrew why not make that  an answer.

Comment: +1 for comment Andrew as you never put it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the direct solution to your problem is:

```
<?php
    $files = file_get_contents('http://example.com/txtfile.txt');
    echo $files;

    $files = trim($files);

    $file = file_get_contents($files);
    echo $file;
?>
```

But this is huge security risk.  Running file_get_contents to open a variable file is risky.